# Resharper is missing in Extensions tab after succesfully installation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

I installed resharper using choco but when I opened VS then resharper is not available in Extensions tab. How can I add it?

Comment: I never installed this using choco, but maybe you need to add some configuration options? The VS integration is disabled by default also when using the GUI installer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big fan of Chocolatey, and I used to install R# and Visual Studio this way too. However, I stopped working this way.

On my machine, I have a regular non-admin account (e. g. `mu88`, for my everyday development tasks) and an admin account (e. g. `admin`). Since Chocolatey highly recommends running all `choco` commands with admin privileges, I also installed R# by executing `choco install resharper` under `admin`. This way, R# gets installed in the user profile of `admin` and is missing for `mu88` (where I'm working with Visual Studio).
I also tried to install R# using Chocolatey under my `mu88` account, which forced me to run all `choco upgrade` commands twice: once for `admin` and once for `mu88`.

Now I'm using the [JetBrains Toolbox app](https://www.jetbrains.com/toolbox-app/) (installed via `choco install jetbrainstoolbox` under `admin`), which works smoothly under my `mu88` account.

So long story short, ensure your Chocolatey installation and Visual Studio profile are running under the same account.